# Filter out multiple emails from a Queryset

Tags: django, email, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter out multiple emails from a queryset in order to stop our employee emails from affecting any exports. I have the following in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_FILTERS = ['email1', 'email2']
```

and I'm trying to use this to filter out any entries in the DB with our emails in the following query:

```
EMAIL_FILTERS = getattr(settings, 'EMAIL_FILTERS')

campaigns = CampaignsSignup.objects.filter(created_date__gte=self._get_start_date(dte), 
                                    created_date__lte=self._get_end_date(dte)).order_by('-created_date')
```

However after trying Q and exclude I can't seem to get it to work. I should also note as much as I would like to be able to use endswith some of the employees are using their personal email address so at the moment it wouldn't be viable.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to filter the entries based on email domains?

Comment: It unfortunately has to be specific emails for now. I just lucked out on the answer though so don't worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've found a solution, but the normal way to do this is with `exclude`:

```
campaigns = CampaignsSignup.objects.filter(
                created_date__gte=self._get_start_date(dte), 
                created_date__lte=self._get_end_date(dte)
            ).order_by('-created_date').exclude(email__in=SAVCHAMP_EMAIL_FILTERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

After throwing everything at it I stumbled upon a way of doing it. Using __in with Q correctly filters out the emails that have been included in the email_filter list in settings.

```
campaigns = CampaignsSignup.objects.filter(~Q(email__in=SAVCHAMP_EMAIL_FILTERS), created_date__gte=self._get_start_date(dte), 
                                    created_date__lte=self._get_end_date(dte)).order_by('-created_date')
```